# How is HttpContext TraceIdentifier generated in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core

How is HttpContext TraceIdentifier (aka Correlation-Id) generated?

I request a page through controller which gives me the following TraceId:
`0HLEACIU86PT6:0000000D`

The page fires an ajax call which has the following TraceId:
`0HLEACIU86PT7:00000005`

As you can see, they are very similar. Is it based on time?

Why didn't I get the same TraceIdentifier?

How can I ensure the same TraceIdentifier?

Comment: The page request and the AJAX request are two separate requests therefore different TraceId.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Kestrel generates the request ID as {ConnectionId}:{Request number}. The connection id is the base32 encoded version of a long using the alphabet 1-9, and A - V. The request count is the number of requests over that connection. The nth request over a specific connection is {ConnectionId}:{n}

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/a48222378b8249a26b093b5b835001c7c7b45815/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Infrastructure/CorrelationIdGenerator.cs

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/0aff4a0440c2f393c0b98e9046a8e66e30a56cb0/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Http/Http1Connection.cs#L446

Comment: And how `ConnectionId` is generated?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/a48222378b8249a26b093b5b835001c7c7b45815/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Infrastructure/CorrelationIdGenerator.cs

Comment: @davidfowl is there a way to override how Kestrel generates the CorrelationId?  I'd like to have it always use a GUID.

Comment: Hi @DaveBlack The HttpContext.TraceIdentifier has get and set defined, So you can overwrite this in a middleware  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.traceidentifier?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

It is `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` base32 encoded.

https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/HttpRequestIdentifierFeature.cs

Comment: This implementation isn't used in Kestrel.