# System.Diagnostics.Activity is null in aspnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We've just updated an aspnet core 2.0 application to 2.1 and have run into a problem with our usage/reliance on `System.Diagnostics.Activity`.

**Background**

We want a consistent 'correlation id' passed across our service boundaries, so that we can correlate log entries per request.

The approach we took was:

- Add a diagnostic listener to the middleware pipeline for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn.Start`
- When this listener was invoked, check if there was a header in the context.request called "Request-Id", and if there wasn't then add one with a value of `Activity.Current.Id`
- Another piece of middleware took care of pushing the "Request-Id" header value into the logging context

This worked just fine in 2.0 and the hierarchical nature of `Activity.Current.Id` meant we could correlate log entries across different services and layers. In 2.1 we are now getting exceptions because `Activity.Current` appears to always be null on the point-of-entry for a request (i.e. the first service that is hit, in this case an API).

I've not managed to find any information that suggests that an activity is no longer automatically started whenever an HttpRequest comes in, but that's what it seems like is happening. Is anyone able to shed any light on what has changed and/or what we're doing wrong?

**Some code**

The startup configure method ...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
        {
           diagnosticListener.SubscribeWithAdapter(new HttpRequestInDiagnosticListener());
           app.UseMiddleware<SetRequestIdHeaderForHttpRequestInMiddleware>();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseSecurityHeaders(Headers.AddSecurityHeaders());

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

... and the custom classes involved

```
    public class HttpRequestInDiagnosticListener
    {
        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn.Start")]
        public virtual void OnMiddlewareStarting(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Middleware Starting, path: {httpContext.Request.Path}");
        }
    }

    public class SetRequestIdHeaderForHttpRequestInMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly DiagnosticSource _diagnostics;

        public SetRequestIdHeaderForHttpRequestInMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource)
        {
            _next = next;
            _diagnostics = diagnosticSource;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {

            if (_diagnostics.IsEnabled("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn.Start"))
            {
                if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("Request-Id"))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Request-Id", Activity.Current.Id);
                }
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you use Application Insights (SDK 2.1+) they set Activity.Current and you can use Activity.Current?.Id or .RootId to get the operation id / correlation ids

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, after days of looking into this, but succinctly YES: in 2.1 activities are no longer started in the same way that they were in 2.0.
https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs#L54-L79

For an `Activity` to start you need to specifically be observing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn`, whereas the code in the question was observing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn.Start`

Unfortunately that isn't the only change in 2.1 that has affected the code in the question, and just changing the Activity Name being observed doesn't make this code work as 2.1 now handles `Request-Id` headers and `CorrelationId` log properties in its own way which interferes with this middleware code.

Comment: How did you solve the last part (Request-id handling in it's own way)?
Looks like in .NET Core 3.0 they are using Activity.Id for ProblemDetails.traceId generation: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ProblemDetailsClientErrorFactory.cs#L50 and there is no way to override it :/

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I gave up following the various aspnetcore teams conversations about having a tracing/correlation/request-id that could carry across service boundaries after it kept getting pushed back first to 2.2 and now (possibly) 3.0. I'm waiting for them to sort this out.

Comment: Me too :) Please post here if you'll find a solution. For now, I'm keeping custom Correlation middleware and adding custom ProblemDetailsClientErrorFactory which uses TraceIdentifier instead of Activity.Id

Comment: any progress at this topic?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` instead of `Activity.Current.Id`. I have similar use case and use `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` to identify requests inside logs. For more info look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694180/5632590

Answer (score -1):

In the current default ASP.NET Core MVC template in Visual Studio 2019, I found following error handler action:

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var requestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    return this.View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = requestId });
}
```

So I think the intended way to receive a traceable identifier in a web application is

```
Activity.Current?.Id ?? this.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier
```

My advice: **Do it the microsoft way**

Comment: And does this carry the common id across service boundaries? i.e. if I log the ID in an API tier, make a call using a standard HttpClient call to another service then will that receiving service have the same trace id? That's the problem I'm trying to solve.