# Tracing every response code from an ASP.NET Core service

Tags: asp.net-core

I'd like to look at every response leaving an ASP.NET 2.1 Core app. This is for instrumentation so rather than add my own middleware, I'm looking to hook in to the built-in diagnostics.

So I've been looking at the AspNetCore code on GitHub for uses of **DiagnosticListener** and **DiagnosticSource** and have found this, below, in `HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs` but its "deprecated".

```
DeprecatedDiagnosticsEndRequestKey = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EndRequest"
```

If I want to log the outbound response code on every call, which diagnostic event key should I look for?

Comment: What solution did you end up using?

Comment: I don't remember and I don't work there any longer, but by random coincidence I'm on SO today to look at a similar topic so I found this just now which might help you - https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/221037/index.html search for HttpRequestOut - might work, not sure.

Comment: This guy's question/answer indicates that .NET Core changed and broke his code in 2.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632031/system-diagnostics-activity-is-null-in-aspnet-core-2-1?rq=1