# HttpContext.TraceIdentifier is always same (and a Guid)

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I am setting up logging for my .NET Core webapi and want to have a unique Id for one request.

After some googling I have found out that Serilog uses `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` for that purpose and it should look something like "0HL0GJPLR7AOD".

If I set a breakpoint in the controller method I get the `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` to be a Guid, and whats worse, its the same every time, not one per request (800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb).

This is also what is displayed in serilog as "RequestId", but my main question is why is `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` not on the format "some text" and why is it same every request?

Comment: How are you registering your services? Scoped, transient, singletons? It's easier to help if you share some code.

Comment: Sure, What services?  (note, that my main issue isnt really about serilog, its about HttpContext.TraceIdentifier in my controller, the controllers are registered with   services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices(); in configureServices and    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }); in Configure() ... hope that was what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will likely be down to where you are hosting your app, the trace identifier ultimately comes from a feature of the hosting platform. If you run your app in Kestrel, e.g. by using the default profile (usually named the same as your project) you'll see a format of ConnectionID:Count (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694180/934407)).

Here's an example of the feature when running as above:

[image: Running on Kestrel]

If you run using IIS/Express you'll see a GUID, and in my testing it is unique per request... Here's the same example on IIS Express:

[image: Running on IIS Express]

Btw, you could set the TraceIdentifier yourself and/or you might also want to look at the [Activity class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md). This takes precedence over the TraceIdentifier generally, e.g. in a default error page:

```
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! (one more character)